# Exception handling using log4j2

Tags: java, exception

I'm new to java..

I'm working on integrating log4j2 to my application...

I have few doubts:-

To print the exception in the logs should we always use try and catch block?

```
try
{
}catch(Exception e){
log.error("print exception");
}
```

how to print throw keyword exception without using try/catch block..

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    public void test(String i) throws Exception {
        if (i.equals("0")) {
            //thowing using throws keyword
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.
For the first questions, for logging an exception, you need the an exception instance. And for catching it, you need a try/catch block for capturing it.
Once you have captured it, you can pass the instance to other method to manage it or delegate on a exception handler. In both cases, you can log it out of the catch block.

For the second, you can throw an exception by invoking the throw statement. Here is the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    public void test(String i) throws Exception {
        try{
           if (i.equals("0")) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't be 0");
           }
        }catch (IllegalArgumentExceptione){
            log.error("Oops: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```